# Prevent react component clearing UI until ajax request completed

Tags: reactjs

I have a React component that adds a loading mask to the UI before an ajax request is started, upon successful GET of data the state is updated and the component itself is then updated. I want to be able to see the previous component in the UI until the ajax request has finished loading. Even by returning null in my render function the previous component is still cleared while the request is loading.

Is there a general approach I should be taking in order for my previous component to not be cleared from view until I render the JSX for my new AJAX component?

```
componentWillMount: function () {
    var self = this;

    loading.init(function () {
        //GET REQUEST, STATE UPDATED WITH RESPONSE DATA
    });

},
render: function () {  
    if (this.state.alerts) {
        loading.loaded();
        return (
            <New Component />
        )
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: In that case, have the API request in the previous component and orute only when the data was retrieved, pass the data as props

Comment: I am using react-router for routing within the app so this isn't possible to my knowledge. Thanks

Comment: In which case are you replacing the previous component and calling API in the current one

Comment: I have a homepage, a link is clicked on that page which navigates to a new route which in turn renders a new component. The new component has the above ajax request in the componentWillMount method and a render function which outputs a JSX component when the AJAX has finished rendering. My issue is I want to the homepage to still be visible up until the render component is called again based on successful ajax request. The issue is as soon as the routing changes the homepage disappears regardless

Comment: Yes that will happen, what you can do is on clicking the link to other project don't use a Link component, rather have a function called on it, which has the AJAX request, after the AJAX request is completed, you can dynamically route to that page and pass the data as props

Comment: OK thanks, I will give this approach a go.